# How to allow write access on system collection of a database in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

With latest meteor update, meteor is trying to do a write operation on `my_database.system.dummy` in my mongo database. I am using external mongo database with authentication enabled. The user I've created has full read-write access to `my_database` database but it can't write to `my_database.system` collection.

How can I allow my user to be able to write to `my_database.system` collection?

**UPDATE** I think I didn't phrased my question right. Problem is with mongo db connection. When meteor tries to connect with mongo, the connection fails because meteor tries to write on "my_db.system.dummy" and db user doesn't have permission to do so, although db user have full read/write access on "my_db". My question is how I can allow the mongo user to be able to write on "my_db.system.dummy" collection. Also I just confirmed that meteor 0.8.2 isn't connecting with mongo either. This is strange because app was working fine till I upgraded to 0.8.3

**UPDATE 2**
I use meteor-up for deployment, but for testing locally, this is how I connect (not I get same error in `mup logs`:

```
sudo MONGO_URL="mongodb://<db_user>:<password>@<database_url>:27017/<db_name>" mrt --port 80
```

And this is the error I get:

```
/Users/charanjitsingh/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
W20140808-09:35:09.241(5.5)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
W20140808-09:35:09.241(5.5)? (STDERR)                             ^
W20140808-09:35:09.260(5.5)? (STDERR) MongoError: not authorized for query on celebvidy.system.dummy
W20140808-09:35:09.260(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Future.wait (/Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
```

Comment: Can you use `meteor mongo` command in your project and make sure that collection with the given name exists?

Comment: I am using external mongo hosted on AWS. Yes that collection exists, mongo creates it.

Comment: Allow/deny rules pass?

Comment: I think I didn't phrased my question right. Problem is with mongo db connection. When meteor tries to connect with mongo, the connection fails because meteor tries to write on "my_db.system.dummy" and db user doesn't have permission to do so, although db user have full read/write access on "my_db". My question is how I can allow the mongo user to be able to write on "my_db.system.dummy" collection. Also I just confirmed that meteor 0.8.2 isn't connecting with mongo either. This is strange because app was working fine till I upgraded to 0.8.3

Comment: How are you connecting to meteor? Can you show us the code? `db.system.*` collections should be for internal MongoDB use only and meteor/you shouldn't be writing to them.